# insert into database other controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, controller

I currently have a basic controller to create reports like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Reports reports)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Events.Add(reports);
        db.SaveChanges();        
        return RedirectToAction("../Home");
    }

    return View(reports);
}
```

Besides that users can create lots more (events, comments, fixes,...) with every time a different controller.

Now I also want to use a kind of logbook where all these actions are stored, so when a user creates a report it has to be added to the logbook but also when he creates an event, adds comment, etc etc...

So how can I add those reports etc to the reports db but also to the logbook db which has different fields and display these on the logbook view?

I thought, I just add my logbook db to the report controller and add to logbook each time a report gets created but my logbook db is different from my report db so that gives trouble...

```
//Add reports to logbook 
private Logbook.CalendarDBContext ldb = new Logbook.CalendarDBContext(); 

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Reports reports)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
db.Events.Add(reports);
db.SaveChanges();

ldb.Events.Add(reports);
```

So I'm looking for a good solution to post (parts of) data (like time, title, description) from different models to the same database when these get created in different controllers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're having an issue because of a type mismatch between your models and what your context is expecting.

The simplest solution would be to simply create the type you need so it can be added to the database:

```
db.Events.Add(reports);
db.SaveChanges();

ldb.Events.Add(new WhateverTypeYouNeed() {
    Title = reports.Title,
    Description = reports.Description,
    //Anything else you need
});
```

I do this in every application I build because the models I take in from the controller are always of a different type than what the database needs.